# JPA 2 case statement allow null in constructor query

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

I have a constructor criteria query.  For the constructor, I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
query.select( builder.construct( MyView.class
    , metaObject
    , builder.selectCase( builder.isNull( metaOtherObject )).when( true, null ).otherwise( metaOtherObject.get( MetaOtherObject_.myDateField ))
));
```

If I use `when(true,null)` then I get a NullPointerException on that line.  If I use something like `when(true,new Date())` then it looks alright.  Problem is, I need to be able to pass a null in there if the OtherObject wasn't found.  How can I do that?

I'm using eclipselink as the provider hitting postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to use the CriteriaBuilder literal or nullLiteral methods.  Something like

```
Expression nil = builder.literal(null);
// or
Expression<Date> nilDate = builder.nullLiteral(Date.class);
// then I can 
blah.when(true, nilDate).otherwise(blah)
```

While my query still fails, it isn't in the constructor portion where I was trying to use just `null` directly.  I believe the other problems are unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0):

Include the stack trace and version you are using.

Note that when() has two method, one that take Object, and one that takes Expression, make sure you are not somehow calling the one that takes Expression.